# One argument insted of two. Either

Tags: haskell

```
instance Monad (Either e) where
        return = Right
        Right m >>= k = k m
        Left e  >>= _ = Left e
```

I found a such piece of code. It is not understandable for me because, after all, `Either` constructor type gets two arguments ( `Either a b` ) and here
took one. I don't understandy why it is possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Type constructors, like normal functions, are curried in Haskell. That means you can give a constructor that takes two arguments, such as `Either`, one argument, and the result is a type constructor that needs only one argument to construct a full `Either`.

The `Monad` typeclass is not for simple types, but for type constructors taking one argument. For example, you have `instance Monad Maybe`, but `Maybe` is not a type, it's a type constructor taking one argument. So you can't make `Either` an instance of `Monad`, since it takes two arguments, not one, and you can't make `Either a b` an instance, since it takes no arguments. You can make `Either a` an instance of monad.

In Haskell, we say that a simple type has kind `*`, a type constructor taking one argument like `Maybe` has kind `* -> *`, and `Either` has kind `* -> * -> *`. `Monad` wants something of kind `* -> *`, and by supplying one type to `Either`, that's what you get.